# Fatal error: Cannot redeclare route() when running PHPUnit

Tags: php, laravel, phpunit

I got a specific problem with PHPUnit.
I had to write our own route() helper, which I require at the very start of the boot process. It all works fine, because Laravel actually asks if a similar named function already exists whenever generating a helper.

When I try to run tests, I get:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare route() (previously declared in
>   E:\laragon\www\fksp\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php:754)
>   in E:\laragon\www\fksp\app\Http\helpers.php on line 30

And I don't know why. Why does PHPUnit think that the Laravel helper is declared before ours?
I could wrap our function into

```
if (! function_exists('route')) {}
```

and it works, but then most likely I will run into problems in the long run with every test that uses the route function?

Any idea or insights how PHPUnit works?

Comment: How are you loading the file that includes your helpers?  Is it require_once or require?

Comment: I use require, require_once does not change anything. It is not that this file is required twice, the other function will be declared first. I don't understand where the test differentiates from Laravel itself tbh.